# MySQL - Hibernate does not create foreign key constraint

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, foreign-keys, innodb

I am, moving my application from Derby to MySQL, and facing the problem that hibernate doesn't create the foreign key constraints while initially creating the tables. All me mappings seems to be correct as they were working fine with Derby.

I am using MySQL Server 5.6, and also MySQL5InnoDBDialect. Also i verified in the MySQL workbench using show create table command that the table are being created using innoDB engine.

MySQL connector used - mysql-connector-java - 5.1.6

Logs:

```
2014-04-21 12:38:29,820 ERROR org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport - Unsuccessful: alter table DEPENDENCY_TRACK add constraint FK25E3373737E62D9A foreign key (TOOL_ID) references TOOL_MASTER
2014-04-21 12:38:29,820 ERROR org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport - Cannot add foreign key constraint
2014-04-21 12:38:30,127 ERROR org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport - Unsuccessful: alter table DEPT_ROLE add constraint FK7E895E3080D96D8 foreign key (DEPARTMENT_ID) references DEPARTMENT
2014-04-21 12:38:30,128 ERROR org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport - Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

Persistance.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="1.0">
    <persistence-unit name="hibernatePersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" /> 
            <!-- <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect" /> -->
            <!-- <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" /> -->
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files">import.sql</property>
        </properties>
        <mapping-file>META-INF/orm.xml</mapping-file>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

database.properties

```
# database properties
app.jdbc.driverClassName    =   com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
app.jdbc.url                =   jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/alt
app.jdbc.username           =   root
app.jdbc.password           =   root
```

Comment: can you provide snip of import.sql for DEPENDENCY_TRACK, TOOL_MASTER and DEPT_ROLE, DEPARTMENT tables and their alter queries.

Comment: import.sql only contain insert queries. iam not creating the tables explicitly through it.

Answer (score 0):

as per MySQL reference [documentation for FOREIGN KEY Constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html), foreign key definitions are subject to the following condition:

> InnoDB permits a foreign key to reference any index column or group of
>   columns. However, in the referenced table, there must be an index
>   where the referenced columns are listed as the first columns in the
>   same order.